# VBA Microsoft Communication Control - Can't insert object

Tags: vba, mscomm32

I can't insert MSCOMM in Controls (VBA). I already register MSCOMM32.OCX in cmd and it was successful. But seems my VBA can't recognized it. I researched a lot. But I can't find any solution. Can someone help me? Thank you so much.

[image: Image here (Add Control (VBA)]

Comment: Are you receiving an error message? How does this "vba can't recognise it" manifest?

Comment: DId you [add a reference Microsoft Common Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34860913/vb6-common-controls-on-windows-10)?

Comment: i didn't receive an error message. Excel seems not recognizing MS Common Controls in "Add Control", I already added MS Common Controls in Add Reference.

Comment: I am using Excel 2013